# MYSQL - Order By price + specific first result

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I use mysql, table `prices` with columns `id, seller, price`.

I want to show the results by price `DESC`, but I want the first result always to be the seller `BOB` no matter if he is more expensive.

I'm trying with:

```
SELECT *
FROM prices 
ORDER BY -price = BOB;
```

But it is not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM prices
ORDER BY (`seller` = 'BOB') DESC, price DESC, seller
```

You can re-try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM prices
ORDER BY (`seller` = 'BOB') DESC,(seller='James') ASC, price DESC, seller
```

Comment: That's perfect, works exactly how i wanted. But now i would like also to have SELLER "JAMES" to be always to the last position. Any idea? :D That means BOB always first, JAMES always LAST, the rest by PRICE

Comment: Now i'm in train when i return to home .. I Try :)

Comment: ORDER BY  case when seller= 'JAMES' then 1 else 0 END, (seller= 'BOB') DESC , -price DESC <br> seems to work :D

Comment: I Edit my Post try it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM prices
ORDER BY (`seller` = 'BOB') DESC, `seller`
```

this will make it so BOB is first, you should visit w3Schools in the sql section for some help I find it to be very useful :)

Comment: I want order by price DESC but BOB to be always nr1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM prices
ORDER BY (`seller` = 'BOB') DESC, `seller`, 'price'
```

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT

```
order by case when name = 'BOB' then 1 else 2 end, -price DESC
```